# Is there a central repository for M4 files

Tags: m4

I've been playing a bit with `m4` and I was wondering if there were anywhere a central repository for m4 'libraries'. m4 is so versatile that I'm sure people have already written useful macros either generic or domain specific.

Answer (score 1):

[GNU autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) uses m4 extensively for its domain specific tasks.
In addition to the macros autoconf provides, there is the [GNU Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) which has more macros.